# Presto Resource Groups

Tags: presto

Presto sets up the resource group, but when running a very complex task, it will cause other tasks to wait. Can the resource group in presto completely limit the use of user resources?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SG1jx.png)

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what you mean by "Can the resource group in presto completely limit the use of user resources"?

Comment: The resources used by the first task have been restricted in the resource group, but when the second task is submitted, it may wait in the queue because there is no resource. The reason is because the first task fills up the resources.